# this.props.obj returned empty object using reducer in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a bug that only happens for sometime. Sometime, when I navigate from one to to this route, in the render method my `this.props.ad` will become empty object thus causing the `ad.name` to render nothing.

```
@connect(state=>state.ads,{fetchAd})
class adDetail extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAd(this.props.match.params.id)
  }

  renderAd() {
    const { ad } = this.props

    console.log('ad', ad) //sometime ad will become empty object in the end

    return(
      <div>{ad.name}</div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props

    return <div>{loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <div>{this.renderAd()}</div>}</div>
  }
}
```

This is hard to debug because I have no idea why is it so. But I manage to trace it will NOT happens when:

i) I reload the page, not navigate by click from elsewhere.
ii) I replaced `this.renderAd()` in the render method with `<h1>test</h1>` and it will not have any error, so most like my reducer is correct.

My reducer

```
 const initState = {
  ad: {},
  loading: true,
  redirectTo: '',
  error: null
}

export function ads(state=initState, action) {
  switch(action.type){

    case FETCHING_AD:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case FETCH_AD:
      console.log(action.payload) // found a hint, ad in render method is empty object but it's always present here
      return { 
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        ad: action.payload,
        redirectTo: ''
      }
    case ERROR_MSG: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      }
    }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

My action

```
export function fetchAd(id) {
  return dispatch=>{

    dispatch({type: FETCHING_AD})

    axios.get(`/ad/${id}`)
    .then(res=>{
      if(res.status===200 && res.data.status===1){
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_AD,
          payload: res.data.data
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(res => { 
      dispatch({type: ERROR})
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `FETCH_AD` dispatched?

Comment: Have you tried console.log in the reducer? Also, redux dev tools may be helpful.

Comment: What is your `default` case in your reducer, and what does your action look like?

Comment: @Tony updated my answer with more code

Comment: Have you checked your network requests to see if the response sometimes isn't successful? It looks like if the request failed for some reason, `FETCH_AD` would never be dispatched, so `ad` would remain an empty object.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere I checked the network tab, the data come in every time, I also checked in the reducer, the payload is always there. Anyway I've changed to use HOC, but there's another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477117/higher-order-function-render-twice-causing-child-component-to-be-triggered