# higher order function render twice causing child component to be triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

I have a protected route, implemented using higher order component, but in my App.js which is the child component, trigger its componentDidMount method, I wonder why is it so..

Route.js

```
...
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/app' component={CheckPermission(App)} />
    <Route exact path='/app/login' component={Login} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
...
```

Auth.js

```
export default function CheckPermission(EnhancedComponent) {
  class Auth extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: PropTypes.object
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.isAuth) {
        this.context.router.history.replace(`/login`)
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
      if (!this.props.isAuth) {
        this.context.router.history.replace(`/login`)
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <EnhancedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

  return connect()(Auth)
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('test') //why is this trigger??
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>App</h1>
  }
}
```

If I have API call in App.js's componentDidMount, it will cause unwanted call, I thought componentWillMount of the Auth.js prevent render to trigger already? I see in my browser, the redirect by Auth.js just worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the replace method in `componentWillMount` will redirect before the render method fired.

You might want to refactor your `Auth.js` code to something like this.

```
export default function CheckPermission(EnhancedComponent) {
  class Auth extends Component {
    render() {
      // Note that we return a <Redirect /> component here early for not giving <EnhancedComponent /> any chance to render itself.
      if (!this.props.isAuth) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
      }

      return <EnhancedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

  return connect()(Auth)
}
```

Comment: So there's no lifecycle method in using HOC? Can you clarifly `There is no guarantee `?

Comment: @JamieAden You don't have to use lifecycle method in HOC. Since basically what you did in `componentWillMount` is a side-effect, which runs synchronously right before mounting. react-router also does something similar in `<Route />` to check if your url match some pattern. So it's very likely that the children will get mount before you actually redirect it in parent component.

Comment: @JamieAden Also, we should prevent introducing any side-effects in `componentWilMount`, as it will create some unexpected behavior like your code does. Actually we should avoid using `componentWillMount` at all, but that's a another case.

Comment: Tried your code above, it doesn't work, is the flow above correct? I got into infinity loop

Comment: @JamieAden I've created a codesandbox to demo this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vnlwnlzqx5 . Welcome any other questions!

Comment: is it ok to do any async action like api call in HOC? basically HOC is just a conditional wrapper? can it do more than that?

Comment: @JamieAden Sure you can, just do it in `componentDidMount` or somewhere safe and call `setState` after that. In your render method, you can conditionally render different component based on your current `state`. That's a question out of this scope though.